# Knowing the key/child name of a known value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Assuming that I know a specific value in a child. How would I get the name of the child using the value that I know.

```
private void couponsearch() {
        final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("My Akiba")
                .setMessage("Enter Akiba Code Here.")
                .setView(taskEditText);
        dialog.show();

        taskEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (taskEditText.getText().length() == 6) {
                    String string = taskEditText.getText().toString();
                    DatabaseReference dref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                    dref.child("codes")
                            .equalTo(string)
                            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        String clubkey = childSnapshot.getKey();
                                        code.setText(clubkey);
                                        System.out.println(clubkey);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

For example, I keyed in the **HUIYUI** value, I want a search that will query if it is present and if yes, I would like to return the name of the child which is **AA 20 MG**

**codes
 -AA 20 MG
 code:"HUIYUI"**

Any help would be highly appreciated.

JSON structure:

```
{
    "Cocacola 300ml": {
        "code": "CCCCCC",
        "value": 20
    },
    "Milk big": {
        "code": "IUDKH",
        "value": 20
    },
    "TUZO Milk": {
        "code": "TZOMLK",
        "value": 20
    },
    "Unga Jogoo 50kgs": {
        "code": "UNKREW",
        "value": 50
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure and responde with @name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specific what field you want to order on:

```
DatabaseReference childRef = dref
    .child("codes")
    .orderByChild("code")
    .equalTo(string)
childRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getKey());
            System.out.println(childSnapshot.getChild("value").getValue());
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: the structure is this way codes/code-XXXXX, value - 25. I know the XXXXX value and i want to know what value it contains plus also its parent child i.e codes for this case

Comment: It's hard to parse your description of the JSON data. Instead please edit your question to include a sample of the actual JSON data (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: {
  "Cocacola 300ml" : {
    "code" : "CCCCCC",
    "value" : 20
  },
  "Milk big" : {
    "code" : "IUDKH",
    "value" : 20
  },
  "TUZO Milk" : {
    "code" : "TZOMLK",
    "value" : 20
  },
  "Unga Jogoo 50kgs" : {
    "code" : "UNKREW",
    "value" : 50
  }
}  @FrankvanPuffelen